# Connect to Access with PHP

Tags: php, database, ms-access

I need to connect to an Access Database through PHP.

I've uncommented "extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll" in the php.ini file.
I've put the database in the same folder as the .php file I'm trying to connect with.

My code so far:

```
$dbName = "data.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName");
```

My error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1811 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\index.php:40 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\Access_Test\index.php(40): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\LAWsites\Access_Test\index.php on line 40
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try making the `$dbName` absolute path with `realpath()` when passing it into the DSN, i have a vague recollection about that the access driver doesn't like relative paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Database Location parameter (`DBQ`) requires an absolute path to your database file:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".realpath($dbName));
```

Comment: Just solved my problem, spent an hour trying to find a solution until I came across your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when the access database was located in the same folder.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1044 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name.
```

I put "./" in front of the filename and it worked.

```
$handler = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=./CIDB.MDB;");
```

Comment: Hi, you better use an absolute path as stated by the accepted answer...

Comment: Thanks @ankabout, I just changed to absolute path and it works too.