# PHP ODBC - connect to local .mdb database

Tags: php, odbc

I've installed the php5-odbc library.

Trying to connect to a .mdb file but keep getting error **Data source name not found, and no default driver specified**.

Code:

```
$dbName = "../../../var/Import/PartsPlaceDB.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

Outputs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified' in [...]
```

PDO Drivers:

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
{
echo $driver.'<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
mysql
odbc
sqlite
```

Comment: This is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250755/connect-to-access-with-php

Comment: Tried it but no luck. keep getting same error. And the error message is a different one.

Comment: check phpinfo(); to make sure you have PDO_ODBC

Comment: Yes. It's enabled.
ODBC Connection Pooling Enabled, strict matching

Comment: Here's a link that has a bit of a different connect string. http://askubuntu.com/questions/356694/how-can-i-connect-to-a-microsoft-access-database-using-php

Comment: No. Still getting same error.

Comment: I was able to get it working after finding this. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-connect-a-database-in-PHP-with-MS-Access-thats-hosted-on-Linux

Comment: For some reason php-odbc and odbclib are not writing in the odbc.ini and odbcinit.ini file.

Comment: I could not find what creates those files.  My /etc/odbc.ini is empty and I had no problem reading an mdb. My /etc/odbcinst.ini had this in it. [MDBTools]
Description     = MDBTools Driver
Driver          = libmdbodbc.so.1
Setup           = libmdbodbc.so.1
FileUsage       = 1
UsageCount      = 1
Both files are owned by root. The permissions are root read/write others only read (664)

Comment: I have no files .so in the system. (Maybe why odbcinst.ini wasn't modified)
sudo find -name "\*odbc\*"
./.odbc.ini.swp
./odbcinst.ini
./php5/apache2/conf.d/20-odbc.ini
./php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_odbc.ini
./php5/mods-available/pdo_odbc.ini
./php5/mods-available/odbc.ini
./php5/cli/conf.d/20-odbc.ini
./php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_odbc.ini
./odbc.ini

Answer (score 3):

The problem is recurrent with 64-bit version. It looks like your code only work on Windows 32-bit.
To solve the problem, you might install this tool: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1). I had the same problem for months but this tool solved mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it happened to me too and I just installed 32 bit apache version and now it works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing the location wrong?

Instead of this

```
$dbName = "../../../var/Import/PartsPlaceDB.mdb";
```

Why not do it like this

```
$dbName = "..\..\..\var\Import\PartsPlaceDB.mdb";
```